# How to navigate from running python script in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-server

I am currently running a python3 script in Ubuntu server 18.04. When i type new commands into the command line it just prints the commands. My terminal window looks like this:

```
mitch@server:`$ cd /home/mitch/folder
mitch@server:`/folder$ python3 main.py
file running ...
text i input just shows like this
```

I need to keep the script running and run other commands, how do i navigate back to:

```
mitch@server:`
```

I'm new to servers/Ubuntu/commands so this may seem trivial! Thank you

Comment: Just open another terminal session...

Comment: Open another terminal session as @MattDMo suggested, or press Ctrl-Z and type `bg<enter>` to keep running the script in the background.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't "navigate" back to that, since you're technically already there, you're just running a script in your shell which is occupying your shell - think of it like you opened a program in full screen.

But you have a few options:

The most basic is to run the script in the 'background' this is a simple as adding a `&` to the end of your command (note that it will still send any message from the script into your terminal - if your script is programmed to send messages that is).

Another option is to use a terminal multiplex like which lets you have multiple terminals open, as well as split screen terminals and many other features. One of the more popular multiplexers is called tmux, just keep in mind that it does have a bit of a learning curve to it, but is extremely useful once you learn it.